# Troubles on the domain of this two variables function.

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

What's the domain of ?

$$f(x, y) = \sqrt{\ln(x) + \ln(y)}$$

---

So, first of all I thought: I cannot write the argument of the root as $\ln(xy)$ since this propert only applies if $x >0$ and $y >0$. In writing it as $\ln(xy)$ I then would be allowed to have both $x$ and $y$ negative.

Then: surely $x>0$ and $y>0$ is required. But also $\ln(x) > -\ln(y)$ that is $x \geq 1/y$.
Clearly this bonds with the condition $y > 0$.

So am I right in saying

$$\Omega = \{(x, y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x>0, y>0, x\geq 1/y\}$$

or am I missing something?

Comment: I think you are right if I am not missing something.

Comment: Yes, that is the correct domain.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Thank you!

Comment: @BobDobbs Thank you too!

Comment: I orefer $xy\ge 1.$ The same thing but looks symmetric with respect to $x$ and $y.$